# Gravar dados em 3 tabelas relacionadas com PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Preciso inserir dados em *3 tabelas* relacionadas usando o *PDO*. A primeira tabela `t_repo_proj (repositórios)`, e a segunda `t_grnte_proj (gerentes)`.

Preciso saber qual gerente está associado a qual repositório. Para isso, criei uma 3° tabela a `t_repo_proj_grnte` que ira receber somente a *SK* (não incremental) das 2 tabelas anteriores.

Segue minha classe de conexão:

```
   

require_once ('C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\Classes\Config.php');

class DB{
    private static $instance;
    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$instance)){
            try {
                self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
                self::$instance->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

public static function prepare($sql){
    return self::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
}


}
```

tenho uma classe crud que herda de DB, mas ela faz o meu select e delete apenas....

Minha classe Gerentes:

```
require_once ('C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\Classes\Crud.php');

class Gerentes extends Crud{
    protected $table = 't_grnte_proj';
    private $nm_grnte_proj;
    private $sk_grnte_proj;

public function setNm_grnte_proj($nm_grnte_proj) {
    $this->nm_grnte_proj = $nm_grnte_proj;
  }

  public function getNm_grnte_proj() {
    return $this->nm_grnte_proj;
  }

  public function setSk_grnte_proj($sk_grnte_proj) {
    $this->sk_grnte_proj = $sk_grnte_proj;
  }

  public function getSk_grnte_proj() {
    return $this->sk_grnte_proj;
  }

  public function insert(){
      $sql = "insert into $this->table (sk_grnte_proj,nm_grnte_proj) values (:sk_grnte_proj,:nm_grnte_proj)";
      $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':sk_grnte_proj', $this->sk_grnte_proj);
      $stmt->bindParam(':nm_grnte_proj', $this->nm_grnte_proj);
      return $stmt->execute();

  }
}
```

Minha classe repositórios:

```
require_once ('C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\Classes\Crud.php');

class Repositorios extends Crud{
    protected $table = 't_repo_proj';
    private $ds_repo_proj;
    private $sk_repo_proj;

public function setDs_repo_proj($ds_repo_proj) {
    $this->ds_repo_proj = $ds_repo_proj;
  }

  public function getDs_repo() {
    return $this->ds_repo_proj;
  }

   public function setSk_repo_proj($ds_repo_proj) {
    $this->sk_repo_proj = $ds_repo_proj;
  }

  public function getSk_repo_proj() {
    return $this->sk_repo_proj;
  }

  public function insert(){
      $sql = "insert into $this->table (sk_repo_proj,ds_repo_proj) values (:sk_repo_proj,:ds_repo_proj)";
      $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':sk_repo_proj', $this->sk_repo_proj);
      $stmt->bindParam(':ds_repo_proj', $this->ds_repo_proj);
      return $stmt->execute();

  }
}
```

E por fim, uma parte do meu index onde eu instancio as classes e chamo o método de inserir.

```
 

           if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])):

               $cargo=$_POST['cargo'];


              if($cargo=='desenvolvedor'){



                   $sk_desenv = $_POST['txt_codigo_pessoal'];
                   $nm_desenv = $_POST['txt_nome'];

                   $sk_repo_proj = $_POST['txt_sk_repo_proj'];
                   $ds_repo_proj = $_POST['txt_repo'];


                   $desenvolvedor->setNm_desenv($nm_desenv);
                   $desenvolvedor->setSk_desenv($sk_desenv);

                   $repositorio->setSk_repo_proj($sk_repo_proj);
                   $repositorio->setDs_repo_proj($ds_repo_proj);

                   $repositorio->insert();
                   $desenvolvedor->insert();

              } 
              if($cargo=='gerente') {


                   $sk_grnte_proj = $_POST['txt_codigo_pessoal'];
                   $nm_grnte_proj = $_POST['txt_nome'];

                   $sk_repo_proj = $_POST['txt_sk_repo_proj'];
                   $ds_repo_proj = $_POST['txt_repo'];


                   $gerente->setNm_grnte_proj($nm_grnte_proj);
                   $gerente->setSk_grnte_proj($sk_grnte_proj);

                   $repositorio->setSk_repo_proj($sk_repo_proj);
                   $repositorio->setDs_repo_proj($ds_repo_proj);

                   $repositorio->insert();
                   $gerente->insert();
              }


            endif;  

        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você vai ter que transformar tudo isso em uma função só, usar beginTransaction(), rollback() no php, isso tudo dentro de um try catch

Comment: Então, as funções insert (repositorio) e insert (gerente) seriam executadas em uma unica função em uma outra outra classe por exemplo? poderia me dar um exemplo? Eu posso fazer uma transação a partir do meu getInstance() da classe de conexao?

Comment: Exatamente isso